# Is it possible to create an android app with full HTML design?

Tags: android, html, user-interface

I want to know if it's possible to design my android app UI with HTML5 and CSS3.
If it's possible, is there any performance issue?

Comment: do you mean mobile web app ? or apps built by PhoneGap ?

Comment: Yes. You can use phonegap, jQuery Mobile, Intel AppFramework.

Comment: Take a look here as well: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html

Comment: @Shivan Raptor Not a mobile web app, A mobile app which the forms and interface designed in HTML.

Comment: Then you're looking PhoneGap-like solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it possible. As rhoadster91 stated, you can use a normal Android WebView which loads your "index.html". All your HTML files should be in the "assets/www" directory. But you'll find plenty tutorials out there which explain everything step by step. Have a look at [Googles developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) site.

A second possibility would be [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). It is a little tool which helps you to deploy your app for various devices (Android, iOS, WP,...) while coding your app only once in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Android has WebView which can render HTML content, but it doesn't provide the same user experience as native apps so its use is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with jquery mobile, native application and phonegap. Building a web application at first seemed very attractive at first as the coding is a lot easier compared to native applications. Here is my opinion based on my research:

1. Using phonegap slows your application responses, it loads slowly and together with jquery mobile the response and load time increases. So I didnot use it.
2. Using jquery alone was no different in Gingerbread mobile and on emulator you can clearly see the lag in switching between one div to another div. I didnot use it either.
3. What I did was use android Webview. I wrote my own javascript and css and placed them on the head section of my page. Used div for changing pages on button click. This approach worked really good giving nearly native performance.